# PHP adding a class to an image url

Tags: html

This is the first time I am doing something using PHP. It might be a very stupid question but I want to add a class to this line:

```
<?php 
$image_url='http://test.haardenenkachels.com/wp-content/uploads/s2dlogo.jpg';
?>

<img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>">
```

How do I add a class to this line?

Thank you so much!

Regards,
Jelle

Comment: A class, as in a CSS class? If so, just `class="your-class-name"` would work and it's not related to PHP.

Comment: what about just typing it? `<img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>" class="myclass">`

Comment: Impressive. You did not think of taking a look into the html documentation, did you?

Comment: explain with some more content

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$image_url='http://test.haardenenkachels.com/wp-content/uploads/s2dlogo.jpg';
$image_class='yourclass';
?>

<img class="<?php echo $image_class;?>" src="<?php echo $image_url;?>">
```

would give you

```
<img class="yourclass" src="http://test.haardenenkachels.com/wp-content/uploads/s2dlogo.jpg">
```

Remember, that you must add the class to your style sheet ... and of course you can find listed in the file where the tag is present img